# how to have a camera follow the player in a rollback game (gamemaker)

Tags: game-development, rollback, game-maker

I generally can't figure it out, I don't know how to keep some input local, rather than it being shared to both pcs

Tried Youtube, however, there was nothing on the subject. Even the official gamemaker channel

this is the best solution I could find, however it only works for single player games

```
    if(player_id == 0)
{
    var cam = camera_create_view(0, 0, 1366, 768);
    
    view_camera[0] = cam;
    view_enabled[0] = true;

    view_set_camera(0, cam);
    camera_set_view_target(cam, self);
    camera_set_view_speed(cam, 5, 5);
    camera_set_view_border(cam, 64, 64);
}

if(player_id == 1)
{
    var cam = camera_create_view(0, 0, 1366, 768);
    
    view_camera[1] = cam;
    view_enabled[1] = true;

    view_set_camera(1, cam);
    camera_set_view_target(cam, self);
    camera_set_view_speed(cam, 5, 5);
    camera_set_view_border(cam, 64, 64);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using the player_local variable, by putting this in my End Step event

```
if (player_local)
{
    var halfViewHeight = camera_get_view_height(view_camera[0]) /2;
    var halfViewWidth = camera_get_view_width(view_camera[0]) / 2;
    camera_set_view_pos(view_camera[0], x-halfViewWidth,y-halfViewHeight);
}
```